# react native children view justifyContent property not working

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-native, expo

Im trying to align items in react native using expo, but the children View justifyContent is not working after aligning items in the parent View. For example:

```
<View>
  <View style={{ borderBottomColor: 'black',borderBottomWidth: 3}}>
    <View style={{flexDirection:'row',justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
      <Text style={{ color: "#6B35E2"}}>Name</Text>
      <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold',color: "#6B35E2"}}>Nico</Text>
    </View>
   </View>
   <View style={{alignSelf:'flex-end'}}>
    <Icon
      name="fingerprint"
      iconStyle={styles.iconRight}
    />
  </View>
</View>
```

Renders the [following image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEejT.jpg). The icon apears below the bottom border, and I need it to be at the right of the second text. Its important to note that the bottom border must not reach the icon. It has to end at the second text. So, I tried to apply a `flexDirection:row` to the parent View like this:

```
<View style={{flexDirection: "row"}}>
  <View style={{ borderBottomColor: 'black',borderBottomWidth: 3}}>
    <View style={{flexDirection:'row',justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
      <Text style={{ color: "#6B35E2"}}>Name</Text>
      <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold',color: "#6B35E2"}}>Nico</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
  <View style={{alignSelf:'flex-end'}}>
    <Icon
      name="fingerprint"
      iconStyle={styles.iconRight}
    />
  </View>
</View>
```

Sadly, [it does not render correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qALTX.jpg). The icon is at the right as expected and the bottom border ends just before, but the `justifyContent:space-between` property applied to the child View does not work anymore. Any ideas? Here is a image with the [expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QV10a.jpg). Its important that the bottom border must not be under the icon, it must end before.

Comment: Post an image/screenshot of the expected result.

Comment: Added in the post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to have a `parent` view with `flexDirection` of `row`. Then inside the parent view there will be two views -

1.) First View With `flex: 1`, `flexDirection : 'row'` and `justifyContent: 'space-between'`

2.) Second View would not have any styles just a simple view.

I've made a [Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@kartikeyvaish/rowitem-component) for this.

You can do something like this

```
<View style={styles.parentView}>
  <View style={styles.firstRowView}>
    <Text>Name</Text>
    <Text>Nico</Text>
  </View>

  <View style={styles.secondRow}>
    <Ionicons name="finger-print" size={24} color="black" />
  </View>
</View>
```

And Styles will be

```css
parentView: {
  flexDirection: 'row',
},
firstRowView: {
  flex: 1,
  flexDirection: 'row',
  justifyContent: 'space-between',
  borderBottomColor: 'black',
  borderBottomWidth: 2,
},
secondRow: {},
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much

Comment: Happy to help. If the answer solved your issue, please consider accepting and upvoting it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `icon` on the same row of `Name` and `Nico` then you need to put the `Icon` component inside the same row of `Name` and `Nico`.

```js
<View style={{flexDirection: "row"}}>
  <View style={styles.futBorder}>
    <View style={{flexDirection:'row',justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
      <Text style={styles.placeholderText}>Name</Text>
      <Text style={styles.dataText}>Nico</Text>
      <View style={{alignSelf:'flex-end'}}>
        <Icon
          name="fingerprint"
          iconStyle={styles.iconRight}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  </View>
</View>
```

That way places Nico at the middle of the row. You also can create 2 rows inside one row like this:

```js
<View style={{flexDirection:'row',justifyContent:'space-between'}}> {/* parent row */}
  <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}> {/* child row */}
      <Text style={styles.placeholderText}>Name</Text>
      <Text style={styles.dataText}>Nico</Text>
  </View>
  <View style={{alignSelf:'flex-end'}}>
    <Icon
      name="fingerprint"
      iconStyle={styles.iconRight}
    />
  </View>
</View>
```

And then if necessary you can adjust the widths

Comment: Im sorry, but sadly your answer does not fullfill the intended result. The first one renders everything at the left of the screen, and the second one renders both text tags squeezed together.

Comment: @NICOLÁSANTONIOPINOLEVA like I said at the end, "if necessary you can adjust the widths". Use the inspect to see your elements size, if you are using chrome just press `ctrl + shift + c` then pass the mouse over

Comment: Yes but that would mean that I would have to adjust manually every time I want to use that View.